# What this error mean : expression must have pointer to object type but it has type struct add_stock in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i, n;
struct add_stock
{
char fullname[30];
int stocks;
char com_name[30];
int shares;
float price;
float total;
int totalmoney;

} add;
int main()
{

printf("Enter full name : ");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", add.fullname);
printf("Enter the no. of stocks you want to purchased : ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

printf("Enter the name of the company : ");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", add[i].com_name);

printf("Enter the no. of shares you want to purchased : ");
scanf("%d", &add[i].shares);

printf("Enter the price of each share : ");
scanf("%f", &add[i].price);

add.total = add.shares * add.price;

printf("Toatl money invested in this stock : ");
scanf("%f", &add[i].total);
}
printf("Total money invested : ");
scanf("%d", add.totalmoney);

return 0;
}
```

In question it's add_stock , not add stock , i write like this becoz it's not accepting question.
So, i get error for "add" saying subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.

Comment: WTB some indentation. And fyi, `%[^\n]s` does *not* do what you think it does. That `s` doesn't belong there. See [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: `add` you have _not_ declared as array, but then you are incorrectly accessing it as add[i], hence the error.

Comment: why s doesn't belong there?

Comment: Because it doesn't. Whatever/whomever told you otherwise was wrong, and I urge you to question their subject-matter expertise going forward.  [See the link I provided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Back to your question, however, `add` is neither a pointer nor an array; hence indexing operator `[]` is not viable; thus your reported error. Expressions like `add[i].com_name` are nonsense because `add[i]` is nonsense because `add` is neither a pointer nor an array.

Comment: so . it's a variable for accessing structure elements.

Comment: If  i declare add as a pointer , then i'm able to use indexing operator [] , but how?

Comment: Look at the posted answer. It demonstrates what is necessary to immediately address your code: make `add` a fixed array. So long as you don't breach that array it should solve that specific error. Declaring a dynamic array and the growth algorithms+code to manage it are beyond the scope of your posted question, and worthy of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare an array of strucuture, you need to define the variable as below,

```
struct add_stock
{
   char fullname[30];
   int stocks;
   char com_name[30];
   int shares;
   float price;
   float total;
  int totalmoney;

} add[20];
```

this makes the add as an array of add_stock elements.
then you can access it as, add[0].total, add[1].price and so on.

If you want to declare an array that need to be having dynamic number of elements, you can do so as below.

```
 struct add_stock* arStock;

 //allocate memory to hold 10 elements
 arStock = (add_stock*)malloc( 10 * sizeof(struct add_stock));

 arStock[0]->total=10;  //access it with ->, instead of .
```

Comment: But can u tell me if i declare add as a pointer , then i am able to use it , but how does it so?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show as you want to declare as pointer to array of struct  elements.